# How to connect to PostgreSQL server that's run on docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

```
mac:camden-market dob$ docker-compose ps
         Name                       Command               State     Ports   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
camdenmarket_bundle_1    sh                               Exit 0            
camdenmarket_db_1        /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up       5432/tcp 
camdenmarket_redis_1     docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up       6379/tcp 
camdenmarket_solidus_1   ./entrypoint.sh bundle exe ...   Exit 2    

dmac:camden-market dob$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b5805a802a8a        postgres            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours         5432/tcp            camdenmarket_db_1
3d4d0bd45e3a        redis               "docker-entrypoint.sh"   19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         6379/tcp            camdenmarket_redis_1
```

I want to connect to postgres db as I did withou docker (psql ...).
I tried

```
dmac:camden-market dob$ docker run -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:latest postgresdb
197402ae06c352ff70651b2888ee5018948e2151886a498c096501ec545249d2
dmac:camden-market dob$
```

But the outputs is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was expected the answer turns out pretty simple. 
Take container id from `docker ps`. For our example for postgres this is `b5805a802a8a`.
And then `docker exec -it b5805a802a8a psql -Upostgres`.